# Django 1.8 deployment error on heroku

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

`git push heroku master` command displays `Push rejected` due to the specifying `Python-3.4.3` in `runtime.txt`. I changed the values because I was using python 3.4 on my windows 7 system.

full error traceback

```
(denv) C:\Users\Saket\denv\musicalguru>git push heroku master
 Counting objects: 7, done.
 Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
 Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 488 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
 Total 6 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
 remote: Compressing source files... done.
 remote: Building source:
 remote:
 remote: -----> Python app detected
 remote: -----> Found runtime python-2.7.10, removing
 remote: -----> Installing runtime (python-3.4.3)
 remote: -----> Installing dependencies with pip
 remote:        Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.3.2 (from -r requirements.txt  (line1))
 remote:          Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.3.2.tar.gz (143kB)
 remote:        Collecting dj-database-url==0.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
 remote:          Downloading dj_database_url-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
 remote:        Collecting dj-static==0.0.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
 remote:          Downloading dj-static-0.0.6.tar.gz
 remote:        Collecting Django==1.8.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
 remote:          Downloading Django-1.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2MB)
 remote:        Collecting django-hvad==1.2.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))

 remote:          Downloading django-hvad-1.2.2.tar.gz (99kB)
 remote:        Collecting django-libs==1.66.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
 remote:          Downloading django-libs-1.66.2.tar.gz (129kB)
 remote:        Collecting django-postgrespool==0.3.0 (from -r  requirements.txt (line 7))
 remote:          Downloading django-postgrespool-0.3.0.tar.gz
 remote:        Collecting django-toolbelt==0.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line8))
 remote:          Downloading django-toolbelt-0.0.1.tar.gz
 remote:        Collecting factory-boy==2.5.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))

 remote:          Downloading factory_boy-2.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
 remote:        Collecting fudge==1.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
 remote:          Downloading fudge-1.1.0.tar.gz (86kB)
 remote:        Collecting gunicorn==19.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
 remote:          Downloading gunicorn-19.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (110kB)
 remote:        Collecting Pillow==2.8.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
 remote:          Downloading Pillow-2.8.2.tar.gz (9.1MB)
 remote:        Collecting psycopg2==2.6.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
 remote:          Downloading psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz (371kB)
 remote:        Collecting requests==2.7.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
 remote:          Downloading requests-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (470kB)
  remote:        Collecting South==1.0.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
  remote:          Downloading South-1.0.2.tar.gz (96kB)
  remote:        Collecting SQLAlchemy==1.0.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))

  remote:          Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.0.5.tar.gz (4.6MB)
  remote:        Collecting static3==0.6.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
  remote:          Downloading static3-0.6.1.tar.gz
  remote:        Collecting wheel==0.24.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 18))
  remote:          Downloading wheel-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (63kB)
  remote:        Collecting whitenoise==2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 19))
  remote:          Downloading whitenoise-2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  remote:        Collecting wsgiref==0.1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
  remote:          Downloading wsgiref-0.1.2.zip
  remote:            Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
  remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
  remote:              File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-okgbhbhf/wsgiref/setup.py", line 5, in<module>
  remote:                import ez_setup
  remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build- okgbhbhf/wsgiref/ez_setup/__init__.py", line 170
  remote:                print "Setuptools version",version,"or greater has been installed."
  remote:                                         ^
  remote:            SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
  remote:
  remote:            ----------------------------------------
  remote: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-okgbhbhf/wsgiref
  remote:
  remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
  remote:
  remote: Verifying deploy....
  remote:
  remote: !       Push rejected to musicalguru.
  remote:
  To https://git.heroku.com/musicalguru.git
   ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
  error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/musicalguru.git'
```

What could be the problem?Can't figure it out.

Comment: You should check what [stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar) you're on; you may need to upgrade

Comment: Isn't cedar-14 the default stack for heroku? and the traceback shows cedar-14

Comment: ah good call, missed the specification on the wrapped line

Comment: nearly a week ago I've successfully deployed (using free account) a project with python-3.4.2 in runtime.txt

Comment: also try it in lowercase **python-3.4.3**

Comment: did that.Still getting som errors.Added the updated traceback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wsgiref` ships with the Python 3 standard library, so you don't need to install it separately anymore. Remove it from your requirements file.